# postgres aggregate subset from group by rows

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm trying to evaluate user loyalty bonuses balance when bonuses burns after half-year inactivity. I want my sum consist of `ord`'s 4, 5 and 6 for user 1.

```sql
create table transactions (
    user int,
    ord int, -- transaction date replacement
    amount int, 
    lag interval -- after previous transaction
);
insert into transactions values
    (1, 1, 10, '1h'::interval),
    (1, 2, 10, '.5y'::interval),
    (1, 3, 10, '1h'::interval),
    (1, 4, 10, '.5y'::interval),
    (1, 5, 10, '.1h'::interval),
    (1, 6, 10, '.1h'::interval),
    (2, 1, 10, '1h'::interval),
    (2, 2, 10, '.5y'::interval),
    (2, 3, 10, '.1h'::interval),
    (2, 4, 10, '.1h'::interval),
    (3, 1, 10, '1h'::interval),
;

select user, sum(
    amount -- but starting from last '.5y'::interval if any otherwise everything counts
) from transactions group by user
```

---

```
 user | sum(amount)
--------------------
 1    | 30 -- (4+5+6), not 50, not 60
 2    | 30 -- (2+3+4), not 40
 3    | 10
```

Comment: My answer should give you the good result now that you explain what you expected as result

Comment: well, It doesn't work as expected with last piece of data I've added over your suggestions. Trying to improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
with cte as(
select *, 
case when (lead(lag) over (partition by user_ order by ord)) >= interval '.5 year'
then 1 else 0  end  "flag" from test
),
cte1 as (
select *,
case when flag=(lag(flag,1) over (partition by user_ order by ord)) then 0 else 1 end "flag1"  from cte
)
select distinct on (user_) user_, sum(amount) over (partition by user_,grp order by ord) from (
select *, sum(flag1) over (partition by user_ order by ord) "grp" from cte1) t1
order by user_ , ord desc
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7d72901e3228b2ec123d13bc954744a8)

Though it is very complicated and slow but resolve your problem

Comment: wow! Looks like right on money! I'm trying to make `create view as (...` out of this anyways. Do you think it will work faster as view?

Comment: certainly it will work better and further you can use it as table

Comment: Another idea is to turn all `with` statements into intermediate views querying each other.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```sql
with last_5y as(
    select "user", max(ord) as ord
    from transactions
    where lag = '.5y'::interval group by "user"
) select t.user, sum(amount)
    from transactions t, last_5y t2
    where t.user = t2.user and t.ord >= t2.ord
    group by t.user
```

Comment: if you write your question in comments of your query how can expect having the good answer ?

Comment: where's the date for which you have to apply the interval ?

Comment: It represented by `ord` field replacement, `lag` is precalculated interval between current and previous transactions

Comment: I've modified my answer if this is what you're looking for. Ord is an int. Is your date saved as integer ?

Comment: No. I appreciate your efforts, but my problem is more complicated. Maybe I have to reconsider question description. Thanks anyways!

Comment: What i want is to not summarize transactions BEFORE `ord` = 4.

Comment: Ok  then i changed my answer to summarize only transactions where ord >=  last transactions with '.5y'. Is this what you were looking for ?